# Does calling an empty function in C invoke UB?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static int foo(){}

int main(){
  if (foo()) {
    printf("OK\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am not very sure abort that, and I didn't find any explain in *ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E)* yet. Maybe I missed it.
So, `if(foo())` is UB in this case?

I test with gcc7.3  aarch64-linux.
`-O0`: prints OK
-`O1` to `-O3`: prints nothing

Comment: And you should never forget that UB allows any behaviour: a true value or a false value with no more explainations. And you are lucky that gcc has no trap int value, because the language would allow `foo` to return a trap value, which could cause the program to crash.

Comment: Empty functions are allowed, but it is not allowed to declare a return value and not return anything. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings

Comment: @RetiredNinja: No, that is not the undefined behavior. The C standard allows a function declared with a non-`void` return type to return by flowing to its closing `}`. The undefined behavior is attempting to use the return value. If the code merely said `foo();` as a function call without using the return value, that would be fine by the C standard. It is the attempt to use the value in `if (foo())` that results in undefined behavior.

Comment: @nielson: It is allowed to declare a return type (not value) and not return a value. See my comment above. The applicable rule is C 2018 6.9.1 12: “Unless otherwise specified, if the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.” (It is “otherwise specified” for `main` that reaching the terminating `}` returns 0.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil My C17 draft doesn't contain the text "unless otherwise specified." I'm using draft ISO/IEC 9899:2017 N2176, which document are you using?

Comment: @Lundin: It is the official version. It does not have a draft number in the place where drafts do. It is ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (E). Draft N3096 for C 2023 (looking like it may be 2024 at this point) has the “Unless otherwise specified”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So they added that text before finalizing C17. Curious... I wonder what the intention was.

Comment: @Lundin: Without the “Unless otherwise specified,” 6.9.1 12 would render a `main` that flowed to the closing `}` undefined even though it is specified in 5.1.2.2.3 1 to return zero. They simply needed to make it clear 6.9.1 12 did not override 5.1.2.2.3 1.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh right, indeed main() would be a special case. As would `_Noreturn int f(void){}` be, I suppose... I'll update my posted answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right (as usual, except when it comes to spelling my name :-) ). I am used to build with settings that warns against this, which I still think is a good idea, but that is another discussion.

Comment: @nielsen: Weird, I do not usually type full names; I use the autocomplete. Sorry.

Comment: @Lundin It's likely possible to reconstruct the final text of ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (E) from [N2310](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf) (an early C2x draft with diff marks from the official ISO 9899:2018) by undoing the diff marks. Indeed, 6.9.1 12 has the "Unless otherwise specified" text with no diff marks.

Answer (score 10):

C17 6.9.1 §12

> Unless otherwise specified, if the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

The caller is using the function's value as part of the `if` evaluation, so your code invokes undefined behavior. This was always the case since the very first C standard.

---

(The text "Unless otherwise specified" likely refers to `main()` which has a special exception, allowing one to omit the return statement, which is then equivalent to `return 0`, but only in `main()`!)

Comment: Absolutely correct, but since the OP couches the question in terms of *calling* a function with an empty body, it is worth emphasizing that the call itself is not a problem, even if the function's return type is not `void`.  The UB arises from *using the return value*, as this answer already expresses.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile a C program you should always enable warnings. With GCC you do that by adding the option `-Wall`:

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
test.c: In function ‘foo’:
test.c:3:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
    3 | static int foo(){}
      | ^~~~~~
```

**Edit:**

Also, *The C Programming Language (Second Edition)*, section 4.1 says:

> In any case, if a function fails to return a value, its "value" is
> certain to be garbage.

Comment: This doesn't really prove anything though. GCC may leave diagnostic messages beyond the requirements of C, and sometimes it fails to display a diagnostic message when the C standard requires one.

Comment: `-Wall` is probably the worst case of a poorly named option. It does *not* enable "all warnings", but (and this is documented) only "all warnings that are always easy to fix". `-Wall -Wextra` is better, and best is *warnings from [the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html) that you can get away with".

Comment: This particular diagnostic is only heuristic.  The missing `return` is not actually a problem in itself as far as the language is concerned, but it is probably not as intended.  An actual issue arises only if an attempt is made to use its return value.

Comment: Enable warnings is good:) But I want to know whether it's UB.